# molecule tests for ansible roles - how to structure to avoid duplication

Tags: ansible, molecule

I have a lot of roles that I want to test via `molecule`, and I'm a `molecule` beginner.

If I create a molecule scenario in each role,  there will be significant  duplicated code.

Is there a  pattern that people use to avoid have many roles with same `Dockerfile.j2`, `molecule.yml`, etc.

Perhaps some kind of composition (through dependency injection) or if that's not feasible some kinda inheritance?

```
$ molecule init role -r stackoverflow
--> Initializing new role stackoverflow...
Initialized role in /private/tmp/stackoverflow successfully.

$ tree stackoverflow
stackoverflow
├── README.md
├── defaults
│   └── main.yml
├── handlers
│   └── main.yml
├── meta
│   └── main.yml
├── molecule
│   └── default
│       ├── Dockerfile.j2
│       ├── INSTALL.rst
│       ├── molecule.yml
│       ├── playbook.yml
│       └── tests
│           ├── test_default.py
│           └── test_default.pyc
├── tasks
│   └── main.yml
└── vars
    └── main.yml

8 directories, 12 files
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `molecule.yml` file, you can specify from where to fetch `Dockerfile.js`. So, you can have a single docker configuration file in the parent folder and share it among all the roles. For example:

```
driver:
  name: docker
platforms:
  - name: instance
    image: ubuntu:18.04
    dockerfile: ../common/Dockerfile.j2
```

More info on the [Docker configuration for Molecule](https://molecule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html#docker) on the official documentation.

You can also share files like `create.yml`, `destroy.yml` or `prepare.yml` among roles, and specify the right path in `molecule.yml`.

```
provisioner:
  name: ansible
  playbooks:
    create: ../common/create.yml
    destroy: ../common/destroy.yml
    converge: playbook.yml
```

More info on the [Ansible configuration for Molecule](https://molecule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html#id22) on the official documentation.

Furthermore, you can share playbooks and tests among different scenarios for the same role.

```
verifier:
name: testinfra
directory: ../resources/tests/
lint:
  name: flake8
```

More info on [sharing across scenarios](https://molecule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#sharing-across-scenarios) on the official documentation.

I'm not aware of any straightforward mechanism to share a `molecule.yml` file across different roles. It would be useful though.